# Calculate percentage for an area of study

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help for generating a SQL for MySQL database.

I have two tables:

- Students
- student_Subjects

**Students table:**

```
+------------+---------+-----------------+
|    id      |  name   |area_of_study_id |
+------------+---------+-----------------+
| 1          | AAA     | 1               |
| 2          | BBB     | 2               |
| 3          | CCC     | 1               |
| 4          | DDD     | 3               |
| 5          | EEE     | 4               |
| 6          | FFF     | 1               |
| 7          | GGG     | 2               |
| 8          | III     | 1               |
+------------+---------+-----------------+
```

**student_subjects table:**

```
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
|    id      |  student_id       | subject_id       |
| 1          | 1                 |       1          | 
| 2          | 2                 |       1          | 
| 3          | 1                 |       3          | 
| 4          | 1                 |       2          | 
| 5          | 3                 |       1          | 
| 6          | 6                 |       1          | 
| 7          | 7                 |       3          | 
| 8          | 4                 |       6          | 
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I need to find out a `subject's area of study` based on `students area of study`. From above students table you can see that students have the freedom to choose the `area of study`. Sometimes, they can choose subjects which are not related to their area of study. So, in this case, we need to calculate `area of study` for a `subject` based on the `student percentages` who have taken the subjects.

**Partial output:**

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
|Total_students |  subject_id    |area_of_study_id | percentage      |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 3          | 1                 | 1               | 75              |
| 1          | 1                 | 2               | 25              |
| 1          | 3                 | 1               | 50              |
| 1          | 3                 | 2               | 50              |
| 1          | 2                 | 1               | 100             |
| 1          | 6                 | 3               | 100             |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

From above partial output, we can see, 3 students choose a subject(i.e subject_id =1) have the area of study `1` and one student is from different area of study (i.e 2). So, we can say `subject_id =1` is from `area of study = 1`.

if percentage 50% for a subject. we can choose any area of study between two, no matter which one.

**Expected output:**

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
|Total_students |  subject_id    |area_of_study_id | percentage      |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 3          | 1                 | 1               | 75              |
| 1          | 3                 | 1               | 50              |
| 1          | 2                 | 1               | 100             |
| 1          | 6                 | 3               | 100             |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail how percentages are calculated for partial and end result?

Comment: Percentages only calculated once. In final out i just filter the partial. In partial, you can see 4 students choose subject_id = 1. However, one is from different area of study. So percenrage calculated : 100 * 3 / 4 = 75 and for single student; 100 x 1/4 = 25.

Comment: @Anam: I think it would be more helpful if you put the names of the subject and the name of the area of study rather than subject id and area of study id respectively. It is very confusing because of the similarity of numbers.

Comment: I didn't because of the relationship. If i have to mention the name of subjects and area of study, i have to create another two tables. In that case, question will be very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT subject_id, area_of_study_id, total_students, percentage
  FROM
(
  SELECT p.subject_id, p.area_of_study_id, p.total_students,
         p.total_students / t.total_students * 100 percentage
    FROM
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) total_students, ss.subject_id, s.area_of_study_id
      FROM students s JOIN student_subjects ss
        ON s.id = ss.student_id
     GROUP BY ss.subject_id, s.area_of_study_id
  ) p JOIN 
  (
    SELECT ss.subject_id, COUNT(*) total_students
      FROM students s JOIN student_subjects ss
        ON s.id = ss.student_id
     GROUP BY ss.subject_id
  ) t ON p.subject_id = t.subject_id
   ORDER BY percentage DESC
) q
  GROUP BY subject_id;
```

Output:

```
| SUBJECT_ID | AREA_OF_STUDY_ID | TOTAL_STUDENTS | PERCENTAGE |
|------------|------------------|----------------|------------|
|          1 |                1 |              3 |         75 |
|          2 |                1 |              1 |        100 |
|          3 |                1 |              1 |         50 |
|          6 |                3 |              1 |        100 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79cf0/16)** demo

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry, I was busy. This query is massive and complex. I am glad that you have helped me which saved a lot of hours of mine. Thanks again.